# Can anyone tell me how to implement ammo types in C#

Tags: unity, c#

I want to implement an ammo changing mechanism for my game and I know how to do it with array index, is there another easy way to implement this feature in C#, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be interested in [How to link my weapons with their corresponding ammo supply in the Unity Inspector?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/143294/39518)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [Enum](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-enum)

```
enum AmmoType
{
    Heavy,
    Light,
    Sniper,
    Energy
}
```

More references: [Unity Tutorials](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enumerations#), [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-enumeration-or-enum/)

Comment: This answer could be improved by summarizing *why* using an `enum` is a good choice for this situation rather than relying on links.